# Чим можна замінити слово «цмулити»?

Tags: вибір-слова

Зараз читаю твір  «Чорна рада», в тексті часто зустрічається слово "цмулити" - «..Геть Мамо, геть! Чоловік не скотина, більше відра не вип’є. І почав знову  цмулити, а ж поки не упав без пам’яті на землю »

А чим можна його замінити, бо воно наче якесь застаріле?

Comment: Раджу пошукати синоніми у словниках синонімів, зокрема синоніми до слова «цмулити» у [«Словниках України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) (вкладка «Синонімія»).

Comment: Ніяке воно не застаріле.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 11, 1980. — Стор. 242.*

> [ЦМУЛИТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/cmulyty)  лю, лиш, недоконалий вид, перехідне дієслово, може
>   вживатися і без додатка, розмовне. З насолодою пити, смоктати. *А
>   чорниця п'є — не нап'ється. — Вона, мабуть, вже цілісіньке відерце
>   вицмулила, — кажу, — та все цмулить* (Марко Вовчок, VI, 1956, 326).

[Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%86%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8)

> **ПИ́ТИ** що і без додатка (алкогольні напої), **ВИПИВА́ТИ, СПИВА́ТИ** *розм.*, **КРУЖА́ТИ** *розм.*,**КРУЖЛЯ́ТИ** *розм.*,**ХИЛИ́ТИ** *розм.*, **ХИЛЯ́ТИ** *розм.*, **ВИХИЛЯ́ТИ** *розм.*,**СМОКТА́ТИ** *розм.*,**ЧЕРКА́ТИ [ЧИРКА́ТИ]** *розм.*, **ЦМУ́ЛИТИ [ЦМО́ЛИТИ]** *розм.*, **ЧАРКУВА́ТИ** *розм.*, **ЧАРКУВА́ТИСЯ** з ким і без додатка, *розм.*, **КЛЮ́КАТИ** *фам.*, **СМИ́КАТИ** *вульг.*, **ЛИГА́ТИ** *вульг.*, **КРУГЛЯ́ТИ** *діал.*, **КУЛИКА́ТИ** *діал.*, **КУБРЯ́ЧИТИ** *діал.*; **ПИВА́ТИ** *розм.* (часто, не раз); **ГЛУШИ́ТИ** *розм.*, **ТЯГТИ́ [ТЯГНУ́ТИ]** *розм.* (перев. із сл. горілка); **ДУ́ТИ** *розм.*, **ХЛИСТА́ТИ** *розм.*, **ХЛЕБТА́ТИ [ХЛЕПТА́ТИ]** *розм.*, **ХЛЕБЕСТА́ТИ** *розм.*, **ДУ́ДЛИТИ** *вульг.*, **ЖЛУКТИ́ТИ [ЖЛУКТА́ТИ]** *вульг.* (у великій кількості); **ЗАЛИВА́ТИСЯ** чим, розм. (надмірно); **РОЗПИВА́ТИ** що, *розм.* (разом з ким-небудь); **ПОХМЕЛЯ́ТИСЯ** чим і без додатка (повторно, на
>   другий день). Порівняння ***напи́тися.***
>   *Єпископ, правду мовити, хильнути чарочку любив.. Козак Мамай також.. вмів клюкати й вихиляти.. Умів він дудлити й жлуктати. Кубрячити, смикати й лигати, Кружати.., смоктати, цмулити.., хлебестати (О. Ільченко); Чого то вони не вигадають, аби б гуляти та горілочку смоктати!* (Г. Квітка-Основ’яненко);